# Set equal height of specific elements using CSS only?

Tags: css

I have 2 columns of data, in each column I have a paragraph and an image. I am wondering if there is a CSS-only method of making the paragraphs have the same height so that the images line up. I know I could loop through with JavaScript to find the tallest paragraph and set the height of the other to that, but I'm hoping to find a CSS solution if possible.

Additionally, I cannot modify the DOM structure.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
}
  .col {
    padding:0 15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fringilla ultrices nulla ac tempus.</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x100" />
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Nam mauris mi, eleifend et rutrum at, dignissim nec elit. Aliquam lacinia tincidunt leo, et pellentesque nibh ultricies ut. Etiam elit purus, blandit ac consequat a, dictum a dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I'm not sure Arup's example does what you expect - images still don't align.</strike> The answer has been updated.

Here's what should work for you:

```
.container {
  display:flex;
}

.col {
  padding:0 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
} 

.col p {
  flex: 1;
}
```

We set the main axis to be our `y` axis by using `flex-direction` and we justify the content such that everything in a `col` div sits at the bottom of this axis. Setting `flex: 1;` on the paragraph allows the paragraph to grow in order to occupy the free space in the div.

Answer (score 1):

Add below styles.

```
.container {
  display:flex;
}

.col {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

[Live Example](https://jsbin.com/horadesuji/5/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for that, too. See the comments in CSS (borders added just for clarity):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
  .col {
    padding:0 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* causes the image to go under the paragraph */
    align-items: flex-start; /* images would stretch over the entire .col width without this */
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  
  .col p {
  flex: 1; /* makes the paragraph grow to the tallest height available */
  border: 1px solid blue;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fringilla ultrices nulla ac tempus.</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x100" />
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Nam mauris mi, eleifend et rutrum at, dignissim nec elit. Aliquam lacinia tincidunt leo, et pellentesque nibh ultricies ut. Etiam elit purus, blandit ac consequat a, dictum a dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```